# Toggling between React Components toggling with state vs React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-component, react-state-management

I was trying to toggle the page with a buttonLink and list elements when I click on the buttonLink. I can basically see 2 popular possible approaches to this:

1. Using **react router and create routes** one for the list button and another for the list elements that opens up when clicking on  on list button element which gets list elements as props in router
2. Pass the props to list element but render it in the same page, but **with state toggle condition**. Example -

   ***this.state.showList===true ?  :***

Here I'm confused to decide between these 2 approaches. I preferably chose the 2nd approach to toggle between components based on state as I'm less comfortable with Router. But if the number of components in that page increases, it is difficult to maintain it using state value.

But I would like to know that standard approach for medium scale applications.

Any examples or pointers would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using both approaches and distinguish between encapsulated business logic and modifying logic. For example you have persons and relations between those persons. So I have 2 routes `<personId>/details` and `<personId>/relations`. With the first you will see person details like name, address, telephone numbers and with the second you see a network of related persons, who are connected with this person. For me I decide between those 2 approaches by what I expect to see after reloading the page (pressing F5). When I'm on the detail page I want to see the details again and also I want to see the relation network again.

But there are some modifying logics like adding a new a new telephone number. Normally you would do this by showing a modal dialog or expanding a form with some inputs and "OK"/"Cancel". When this dialog is opened and doing a page reload I would expect to see the person details again. So I'm implementing this dialog via `{this.state.showAddTelephone && ...}`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion just go with `react-router`. Routes are used in multiple areas of the app. The logic of conditional rendering can introduce too much complexity if it's being used in a lot of places. It would be easier to just take the declarative approach of the router with no logic behind it.

Comment: Thanks for responding. This is straight and helpful

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.